# GKE - Stackdriver Kubernetes Monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

Following the steps provided in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/installing).

I was looking into better monitoring of our GKE cluster and so thought I'd try out the beta kubernetes Stackdriver monitoring. My cluster version is 1.11.7 (later than the suggested 1.11.2) and I created the cluster with the  `--enable-stackdriver-kubernetes` flag.

In the cluster details Stackdriver logging and monitoring is listed as 'Enabled v2(beta)' however in the stackdriver resources menu the 'kubernetes beta' option will simply not appear [as shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fXuv.png)

I have also confirmed fluentd, heapster and metadata-agent pods are running within the cluster as suggested by the docs.

Any possible suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, James - any chance you can try opting out of the "beta" features and opting the cluster back in to see if that helps?

Comment: Hi James - can you clarify what you mean by "in the stackdriver resources menu the 'kubernetes beta' option will simply not appear"? A screenshot would be really helpful :)

Comment: @YuriGrinshteyn I will try that today and let you know!

Comment: @sethvargo I will add a screenshot showing the menu in my post.

Comment: @YuriGrinshteyn So after opting out and in of the feature a 'Kubernetes Engine' option has been added to the resources menu in Stackdriver but this is not the same thing as the Kubernetes Beta monitoring option I am expecting to appear.

Comment: That's progress......?  Would you be able to create another cluster to see if this issue happens there again?

Comment: @YuriGrinshteyn Thanks for your assistance, see answer below :)

Comment: Excellent - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I managed to resolve this issue:

- Firstly the 'Kubernetes Beta' option appeared in Stackdriver appeared without me making any changes to the cluster(Slightly annoying)
- I gave the clusters service account the appropriate monitoring and logging roles.